# Should I do ORDER BY twice when selecting from subquery?

Tags: postgresql

I have SQL query (code below) which selects some rows from subquery. In subquery I perform ORDER BY.

**The question is**: will order of subquery be preserved in parent query?
Is there some spec/document or something which proves that?

````
SELECT sub.id, sub.name, ot.field 
  FROM (SELECT t.id, t.name
          FROM table t
         WHERE t.something > 10
      ORDER BY t.id
         LIMIT 25
) sub
LEFT JOIN other_table ot ON ot.table_id = sub.id
/**order by id?**/```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will order of subquery be preserved in parent query

It might happen, but you can not rely on that.

For example, if the optimizer decides to use a hash join between your derived table and `other_table` then the order of the derived table will not be preserved.

If you want a **guaranteed** sort order, then you **have** to use an `order by` in the outer query as well.

Comment: It seems to me that the `ORDER BY` plus `LIMIT` defines specifically what the subquery's result set would be.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: yes, but the result of that sub-query is not guaranteed to be used in that order e.g. in the join. And if parallel query kicks in this again can change. It is very likely that the order is preserved but there is absolutely no guarantee.

Comment: I get you bro +1, just saying that `ORDER BY` may not be meaningless.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: you are right, it is most certainly needed in the derived table to make the `limit` work properly.